# How to log usernames using anonymous authentication is IIS?

Tags: authentication, iis, oracle11g, windows-authentication

We have an application architecture where there is an oracle 11g database running on a linux platform and a windows machine which has a IIS web-server configured with a virtual directory primarily to publish documents (doc,pdf etc).

The database store URL links to these documents, all documents also need to be indexed using an Oracle Text index and we also need to log users that access these documents via IIS.

My problem now is that to enable user logging in IIS I believe I need to enable only Windows Authentication because when I enable Anonymous Authentication then the cs-username in the log files turns up empty. On the other hand I want to be able to use Anonymous Authentication as well to let my Database access the files without any authentication issues?

Can you please suggest anyway that i can get around this problem?

Best Regards.

Comment: How is your database accessing these files ?

Comment: We just store the urls and descriptions in a table which oracle can then use to index the files contents. All contents are available to oracle through the URL when we use anonymous authentication because basically no authorization is required at the web server end. However if we use Windows Authentication then oracle can't access the files as the db is just running from local oracle user on the Linux machine.

Comment: So you are also reading the files from Oracle?

Comment: Yes, for indexing the file contents (they are all OCR'ed documents) through Oracle Text so that they can be searched.